# Cucumber/Capybara Test Failing "expected to find css ".singer-row" but there were no matches"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, shopify

I keep failing one of my cucumber CapyBara/Cucumber tests and I can't figure out why. Here is the test:

```
Then /^I should see that the customer is a singer$/ do
  expect(page).to have_css('.singer-row')
end
```

If I pry into that test and run "expect(page).to have_css('.singer-row')" it comes back **true**. In browser I can see the element right there.

Here is the error:

```
expected to find css ".singer-row" but there were no matches (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

Here is the erb:

```
 <% @singers.each do |singer| %>
          <tr class='singer-row'>
             <td>
...
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it. Had to add

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
```

to my env file. Capybara was looking for the css element before it had loaded.

Comment: Btw, if you only need a longer delay for one expect you can do have_css(('.singer_row', wait: 5). And if for a specific test/scenario you can wrap it in using_wait_time(5) { ....  }

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be with your page size while running test cases. Sometime internal browser open in very small dimension so it fetch mobile view in background.

So try take screenshot of your page inside test case where you are getting errors.

If this was the case try add below code and you are done.

```
Before do |scenario|
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
end
```